# Problema com acentos e porta no localhost

Tags: mamp

Alguém sabe como configurar o charset?

O problema é que esta aparecendo assim:

> Informa��es

Imagem:

[image: erro acentos]

E outra, meu localhost está em: `http://localhost:8888`, onde eu configuro para deixar somente `http://localhost`?

Comment: O importante é você definir qual vai usar e configurar o editor, o servidor e tudo o mais da aplicação para ficar igual. Se alguma página velha não ficar correta, quase todos os editores de código permitem você abrir em um formato e salvar em outro para corrigir. Mas se o servidor não estiver configurado ANTES disso, você pode estar arrumando na tela, mas fazendo exatamente o inverso do que quer. Uma alternativa é usar htmlentities, até se decidir. Exemplo: se no source estiver escrito `acentua&ccedil;&atilde;o` vai sair certo no navegador (`acentuação`) em qualquer charset.

Comment: Então era disso que eu estava falando ._. como o charset esta iso-8859-1 e está dando erro de acentuação pois a do servidor provavelmente está utf-8. Eu só queria saber onde mudar o charset do MAMP em sí xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São duas perguntas de natureza muito diferente, mas postadas como uma só, seria interessante que as próximas fossem feitas em separado. Em todo o caso, lá vai:

### Definindo os headers de charset do Apache:

No arquivo "httpd.conf" você precisa desta entrada:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

(ou iso-8859-1, se preferir, entre outros. O mais adequado depende da finalidade da sua aplicação, não vou entrar neste mérito nesta resposta)

A localização do arquivo varia de distribuição para distribuição, por exemplo `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, ou em parte dos Linux em `/etc/httpd/conf`.

É importante que, caso você também defina o *charset* em seus arquivos HTML, mantenha-os coerentes com o *charset* do Apache, para evitar resultados inesperados.

### Para acessar o servidor sem especificar porta:

Por padrão é 80 a porta do HTTP, e 443 a do HTTPS.

Se quiser usar qualquer porta diferente destas, realmente é necessário digitar o URL no formato servidor:porta.

No Apache, isto é definido por padrão em:

```
Listen 80
```

ou mesmo

```
Listen ENDERECO_IP:80
```

para hosts virtuais, depois dos `:` destas diretivas

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: É isso mesmo ;) Muito obrigado!